# getting the WHERE from an apache JENA ARQ Query

Tags: sparql, jena, apache-jena, jena-querybuilder

Is it possible to get the WHERE Clause from a Query org.apache.jena.query.Query ? Haven't found no info enywhere, no documentation anywhere.

Imagine I create a query from a String

```
String queryString = "    
SELECT ?name ?mbox
    WHERE
      { ?x foaf:name ?name .
        ?x foaf:mbox ?mbox }";

Query query = QueryFactory.create() ;
```

For example, I can get the variables that the query will request using the query.getResultVars()), but I cannot get any manner to get the WHERE clause/expression or however you wanna call. Just interested in getting this part:

```
  { ?x foaf:name ?name .
    ?x foaf:mbox ?mbox }
```

Here's Query API:
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Query.html

Comment: `Query::getQueryPattern()` returns an object of type `Element`, which is basically the part of the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKSW . Why have not written as an answer? I'll accept and can be useful for other people in the future, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Query::getQueryPattern()` returns an object of type `Element`, which is basically the part of the WHERE clause.